# Problems installing scipy with pip on 64-bit Windows 7 for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pip

I am trying to install `scipy` with `pip` without much success. I am using 64-bit Windows 7. Is it supposed to be this difficult? I was able to `pip install` other packages without issue.

I have tried:

1. `pip install --upgrade scipy`

   `Collecting scipy
     Using cached scipy-1.0.0.tar.gz
   Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
     Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... /`

But it fails to complete after a full 8 hour work day. I tried twice.

2. going [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) to download `scipy‑1.0.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`, `cd` to its directory, then `pip install scipy‑1.0.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`.

But I got the following error.
`Requirement 'scipy\xe2\x80\x911.0.0\xe2\x80\x91cp37\xe2\x80\x91cp37m\xe2\x80\x91win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
scipy‑1.0.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

I thought maybe the dashes in the file name were messing things up, so I enclosed the file name in backticks, which didn't work, then quotes, which also did not work.

2b. Based on a comment below, "`cp37`" in the `.whl` file above means that it is for Python 3.7. So I repeated the steps for 2. except with the correct file:

```
pip install scipy-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
scipy-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

2c. Perhaps I don't have 64 bit Windows and again chose the incorrect file. So I tried:

```
pip install scipy-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
scipy-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

To be more sure that I have 64-bit Python:

```
$ python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64
```

3. upgrading pip before re-attempting the above but I am already using the latest version (9.0.1). `pip install --upgrade pip`
   `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. `pip -V` `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`
4. I tried: `easy_install scipy` but got
   `-bash: easy_install: command not found`
5. I thought, "maybe I am getting these errors because I have already installed `scipy` before." I tried `pip list` but did not see `scipy` on the list.

   `appdirs (1.4.3)
   asn1crypto (0.22.0)
   attrs (16.3.0)
   certifi (2017.11.5)
   cffi (1.9.1)
   chardet (3.0.4)
   cryptography (1.8.1)
   Cython (0.25.2)
   ecdsa (0.13)
   enum34 (1.1.6)
   flickrapi (2.3.1)
   google-api-python-client (1.6.4)
   httplib2 (0.10.3)
   idna (2.6)
   ipaddress (1.0.18)
   marisa (0.0.0)
   mercurial (4.0)
   numpy (1.11.2)
   oauth2client (4.1.2)
   oauthlib (2.0.6)
   packaging (16.8)
   paramiko (1.16.0)
   pip (9.0.1)
   ply (3.9)
   pyasn1 (0.4.2)
   pyasn1-modules (0.2.1)
   pycparser (2.17)
   pycrypto (2.6)
   pygobject (3.22.0)
   pyOpenSSL (16.2.0)
   pyparsing (2.1.10)
   requests (2.18.4)
   requests-oauthlib (0.8.0)
   requests-toolbelt (0.8.0)
   rsa (3.4.2)
   service-identity (16.0.0)
   setuptools (34.3.2)
   six (1.11.0)
   Twisted (16.4.1)
   uritemplate (3.0.0)
   urllib3 (1.22)
   wheel (0.30.0)
   zope.interface (4.3.3)`
6. I thought, "maybe I am missing a dependency." I checked and believe I have all dependencies (i.e. `numpy (1.11.2)`, `wheel (0.30.0)`)
7. I don't have `sudo` so I can't try a sudo install. `$ sudo pip3 install scipy`
   `-bash: sudo: command not found`
8. I have not tried Anaconda/virtualenv. I'd like to avoid that, if possible, since it is foreign territory.

Comment: Go to [Gohlke](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) and download the version of scipy that matches your version of Python; call the file f.whl. Then at a command prompt, in the folder where you downloaded it, do `pip install f.whl`.

Comment: @BillBell Have you missed point 2?

Comment: @phd: apparently so. :)

Comment: You mention **Py2.7** in the title of your question. But, in point 2, you mention downloading scipy‑1.0.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl which is for **Py3.7**. Pls clarify. If you are really using Py2.7 then it wouldn't matter that the Py3.7 version of scipy for Windows is screwed up somehow.

Comment: @BillBell Thanks for clarifying Bill. I didn't know that cp37 meant "for Py3.7". I tried with the appropriate files without luck (details in 2b. and 2c.).

Comment: *`scipy-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` is not a supported wheel on this platform.* most probably means that you have 32-bit python. Lets check it: please run `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: why not install Anaconda?

Comment: @BillBell $ python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64 (also updated in original question)

Comment: If you're in a Windows environment why do you sometimes show a '$' prompt?